# How to view data being received by other applications?

Tags: java, android, http, packet-sniffers

I'm not sure if this is possible but on my Android phone, I am trying to create an application with Android Studios that can read and display data being sent to other applications on my phone from the internet. For example, I have a game on my phone that when started, gets data from an online server telling me how much gold I have. Is it possible to create an application that views all the data that gets sent to my phone from the internet so I can see on my application how much gold I have assuming that the data is not encrypted? If the data is encrypted, is it possible to view the data after its decrypted by the game?

Comment: Such a program is called a sniffer (sometimes "packet sniffer" or "TCP/IP sniffer"). Making one is possible but not easy. For Android, it may be a requirement that the phone is rooted.

Comment: @S.L.Barth thanks, I'll start researching about that